# VNC Client that can send Ctrl+Alt+Delete?

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there a VNC Client for OS X that can send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Delete</kbd>? I've googled, searched have not found. I frequently VNC into Windows machines and need to send this key combo in order to log in.

Comment: Off topic: I recommend using NoMachine as remote desktop solution. It runs waay faster than VNC service and also has possibility to send CRLT+ALT+DEL to Windows server (unfortunatelly from menu like in @Dave answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iTeleport](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/connect/mac) is my VNC client of choice, and does precisely this.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

The built-in **Screen Sharing** application on OS X is a VNC client that can send Ctrl-Alt-Del:

Laptop keyboard: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

Full-size keyboard: <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

Comment: I'll note that, for a full-sized Apple keyboard connected to a laptop, the full-size keyboard command sequence fails. Just issuing the laptop keyboard sequence on the laptop itself was the solution (since there's no fn key on my full-sized Apple keyboard).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a Mac and screen sharing on a Windows machine, use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Apple Remote Desktop can send Control Alt Delete:

> If you use Remote Desktop to administer a PC that's running VNC, you may be wondering how to send the Ctrl-Alt-Del command (Control-Alternate-Delete) from a Mac to the PC. Though Mac and PC key mapping differs, you can use an alternate key combination in Remote Desktop 2.0 and later to send the command.
>
> For full-size (desktop) keyboards, use Control-Option-Forward Delete.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22781

Comment: Here's how to send Control-Alt-Delete on a OSX laptop or compact keyboard: fn-control-command-delete.

Answer (score 6):

After a day of trials this worked for me <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative. This worked for me in a slightly different and more complicated setup (connecting from a Mac to a Linux server through SSH and then from the Linux server to a Windows Server 2016 server through Remote desktop protocol using the `rdesktop` Linux RDP command line client).

In Windows:

1. Click Start menu
2. Click in the search bar
3. Type "powershell"
4. In the search results, click "powershell.exe"
5. In the PowerShell shell that opens, type the following:

   ```
   Powershell -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -command "(new-object -ComObject 
   shell.application).WindowsSecurity()"
   ```

If PowerShell is not available, instead search for "cmd.exe" and in the cmd prompt, type:

```
explorer shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Taken from: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9c2ea402-087a-40a0-83de-170b49fdaac5/how-to-change-password-in-rdp-session?forum=winserverTS

Note: if your Mac keyboard layout is not English US, it might be hard to get the `{`, `}` characters in cmd.exe. In that case try the following:

- Change you keyboard layout on your Mac to English US (use System Preferences)
- In X11's preferences, check "Use system keyboard layout"
- In Windows, make sure to also set the keyboard layout to English US.

Comment: How does this solve the Ctrl-Alt-Del issue described in the question? And what role does X11 play in all this?

Comment: this has the effect of emulating Ctrl-Alt-Delete, so whatever the OP wanted to do by typing Ctrl-Alt-Delete (eg. changing his/her password in a corporate environment) can then be achieved. However I agree that if ctrl-al-del is needed to *login* then it might not be a good answer

Comment: Ah. And how does X11 play a role in this? There is no X11 on macOS usually

Comment: As I wrote, my setup is mac--(ssh -X)-->linux--(rdesktop)-->windows, so since rdesktop opens a graphical window it shows up as a X11 window on mac